# EF Core: drop and recreate database when server restarts

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

We have an ASP.NET Core MVC application with Entity Framework Core in it. We have added a custom `Testing` environment to the existing `Development`, `Staging` and `Production` environments. Now, we would like the application to drop and recreate (or at least truncate) the database every time the application starts in this new Testing environment.

Is there an automated way how to achieve this behavior? Or do I have to manually call `RemoveAll` on each `DbSet` in the database context?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call [dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade#Methods)

> Ensures that the database for the context does not exist. If it does
> not exist, no action is taken. If it does exist then the database is
> deleted.
>
> Warning: The entire database is deleted an no effort is made to remove
> just the database objects that are used by the model for this context.

Then call `dbContext.Database.Migrate()` to create new (empty) DB and migrate to latest version.

Comment: BTW, it looks very "dangerous" to have production code with "DROP DATABASE" logic inside, even activated by some config/start params. You are starting countdown to production DB dropping (by human mistake) once you commit this to repo. Instead, drop database from separate script before staring your app with testing configuration.